# How to synchronize iTunes to a folder while leaving it intact?

Tags: macos, itunes

I have a folder full of music that I'd like to keep intact. However, I would like to synchronize this with iTunes. What's the best way of doing this?

Comment: synchronize how?

Comment: @Nifle: That's the question! How to do it?

Comment: iTunes is meant to be used as library management software. They only added the ability to *not* use it this way quite late. I don't think it's possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this will help

[iTunes Finally Adds Watched Folder to Automatically Add New Music](http://lifehacker.com/5356619/itunes-finally-adds-watched-folder-to-automatically-add-new-music)

Comment: Unfortunately not, since it requires music to reside in that folder and it will be moved around to iTunes' will. I tried this and it's horrible :(

Answer (score 1):

iTunes doesn't synchronize.  You need to tell it when you've got new music.
That said, this is how you do it;

Launch iTunes, and in Preferences, Advanced - UN-check the, "Copy files to iTunes media folder when adding to library."

Now drag your folder into iTunes and it will add all your songs.

Comment: All fine and dandy but almost all popular media players have a watch/sync folder feature, there is no way to do this other than automator?